# How to load Javascript with imported modules?

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am trying to import modules from tensorflowjs, and below is my code.
test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

test.js

```
import * as tf from "./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs";
import {loadGraphModel} from "./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter";

const MODEL_URL = './model.json';

const model = await loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
const cat = document.getElementById('cat');
model.execute(tf.browser.fromPixels(cat));
```

Besides, I run the server using `python -m http.server` in my command prompt(Windows 10), and this is the error prompt in the console log of my browser:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Comment: Does the error tell you what line it's on?

Comment: It's a server error. Try using the TensorFlow CDN.

Comment: @sean-7777 I have added the script tag as edited in the post above, but the error is still there.

Comment: @RShields The error is from the first two import lines from my test.js

Comment: @Jason Remove the imports too. You also need the `tfjs-converter` CDN.

Comment: I managed to solved it as I cannot import the whole module, but only the javascript. E.g. import import * as tf from "./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/tf.js";

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following python script to serve your files:

`serve.py`

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import sys

PORT = 8000
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    PORT = int(sys.argv[1])

class HttpRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    extensions_map = {
        # '': 'application/octet-stream',
        '': 'text/html',
        '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
        '.html': 'text/html',
        '.png': 'image/png',
        '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
        '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
        '.css': 'text/css',
        '.js':'application/x-javascript',
        '.wasm': 'application/wasm',
        '.json': 'application/json',
        '.xml': 'application/xml',
    }

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost", PORT), HttpRequestHandler)

try:
    print(f"serving at http://localhost:{PORT}")
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

then:

`python ./serve.py 8000`

By default, `http.server` does not take care of mime types. The above scripts indicate which mime type to use in the response header depending on the extension of the file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your script, however the problem still exists. The error remains the same, do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

If you use Node.js, you can use the `http-server` package to serve your files.

### Install

```
npm install --global http-server
```

### Use

```
http-server
```

Or alternatively, use: `npx http-server`

See the documentation for more [details and options](https://github.com/http-party/http-server#usage)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have tried this and is having the same issue